Flutter web app not starting in release mod
i build flutter web app and when from build/web/index.html i run index.html file error occur in console
Error:
Access to internal resource at 'file:///D:/manifest.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, edge.
Uncaught ReferenceError: _flutter is not defined
at index.html:46:7
i found no solution yet please help me to find one.
Moreover i am using sqflite web package(sqflite_common_ffi_web: ^0.4.3+1) in my app

are you sure that the remote system ahas a d: drive?

D:\Inventory App this is my project path

web appliaction can only access files from below build/web/  so d:\manifest can't be read

i appreciate your support but got the answer by my own
1-Open your terminal or command prompt.
2-Navigate to the directory where your Flutter web app is located.
3-Run the command: python -m http.server (for Python 3) or python -m SimpleHTTPServer (for Python 2).
4-This will start a local server on port 8000 by default.
5-Open your web browser and go to http://localhost:8000.
